# Make all text with font Helvetica have the font Arial in jQuery

Tags: jquery, fonts

I need some jQuery magic that will look for all text on a page with a given font (say Helvetica), and change the font of only that text to something else (say Arial).

Comment: Is there a proper reason for this, or could you use CSS instead? Feels like doing something like this with JS is bad practice and that it should be done with CSS if possible.

Comment: I'm having visions now of a html page where all elements have a style attribute defining a different font-family!

Comment: it sounds like a useful userscript to me. If you don't like the font Helvetica (disclaimer: I like it), install something that changes every webpage that uses it to Arial.

Comment: Usually, you want to go the other way around. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, I checked it on my site and it changed font properly.

```
$('body').filter(function() {
    return ( $(this).css('font-family').indexOf('Helvetica')>-1);
}).css('font-family', 'Arial');
```

Comment: This is the best solution of the two currently posted; but I still maintain that this isn't something you should do; there's probably a better way than using JS. I mean, search-and-replace in all your style sheets would certainly do the same thing.

Comment: @You - not that I disagree, but '...is the best solution' doesn't do much to explain why it is the best solution, it's a plain endorsement - it would be more useful to me, Thinker, and everyone else to put a bit of substance behind it.

Comment: @karim79: It's better because it uses `filter` instead of `each`; which makes for prettier and more readable/understandable code. Other than that the two solutions are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but since I cannot yet comment on other people's answers, I'm placing my comments here in an answer.

Thinker's answer above will not work (or at least there are cases where it will not work).

Thinker's code is as follows (I'm copying it here in case he can edit his answer):

```
$('body').filter(function() {
return ( $(this).css('font-family').indexOf('Helvetica')>-1);
}).css('font-family', 'Arial');
```

What this code will do is change the font to Arial for *any* font family which *contains* Helvetica.  That includes font families where Helvetica is being used as a fallback, and so very probably is not always displayed.

You can also read the answers and comments in the following post:

[Changing Body Font-Size based on Font-Family with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271477/changing-body-font-size-based-on-font-family-with-jquery)

which contains similar code along with a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If everything were defined via CSS, have you ever thought of spawning your own `@font-face` definitions, overriding Helvetica?

For example, if everything is defined to render in Helvetica, like in this statement:

```
* {

    font-family: Helvetica;

}
```

You may then append a @font-face statement to your style sheet, which would now look like this:

```
@font-face {

    font-family: 'Helvetica';

    src:    local('Anivers-Regular'),
        local('Anivers Regular'),
        url('typeface.Anivers.Regular.otf') format('truetype');

}
```

It works on in-line-styled elements like `<h4 style="font-family: Helvetica;">aw</h4>` too.

In that way, everything Helvetica would be automagically rendered in (, e.g.,) Anivers, and this snippet works with or without double quotes.  List PostScript name, Full name + style, then an URI for cross-browser compatibility.  If the fallback is on Helvetica, this CSS magic would work.  Plus, you get free performance overhead in this way since the browser, instead of your script, does the substitution for you.

Unfortunately, Internet Explorer hates .otf files for no apparent reason and you would need an utility called ttf2eot just in case.

—

This is an ugly hack and shall live in your production code for too long.

By the way, what’s the scenario and why would you want to do this — substituting a better-looking typeface with an inferior one?

If you later changed your mind and would like to use the “real” Helvetica somewhere else, you will have to swizzle it under another name.  Tedious work isn’t it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my Google Chrome extension:

```
var replacement = "Helvetica";
var toReplace = new RegExp("[\\'\\\"\\s]*(Arial|Some|Other|Fonts)[\\'\\\"\\s]*(?=,|$)", "gi");

function replaceFont (toReplace, replacement) {
    // Adjust style sheets
    if (document.styleSheets) {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
            var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];

            if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
                for (var j = 0; j < styleSheet.cssRules.length; j++) {
                    var cssRule = styleSheet.cssRules[j];

                    // Replace in font-family attribute
                    if (cssRule.style.fontFamily.match(toReplace))
                        cssRule.style.fontFamily = cssRule.style.fontFamily.replace(toReplace, replacement);

                    // Replace in font attribute
                    if (cssRule.style.font.match(toReplace))
                        cssRule.style.font = cssRule.style.font.replace(toReplace, replacement);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Adjust inline styles
    $('body').find('*').each(
        function (i) {
            if ($(this).css('font-family').match(toReplace))
                $(this).css('font-family', $(this).css('font-family').replace(toReplace, replacement));

            if ($(this).css('font').match(toReplace))
                $(this).css('font', $(this).css('font').replace(toReplace, replacement));
        }
    );

    // Adjust font tag properties
    $('body').find('font').each(
        function (i) {
            if ($(this).attr('face').match(toReplace))
                $(this).attr('face', $(this).attr('face').replace(toReplace, replacement));
        }
    );

}
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/goblindegook/Allvetica/blob/master/allvetica.js).

Comment: Now that I look at it, that regular expression in `toReplace` should probably looking ahead for delimiters and ignoring whitespace.

Comment: Whitespace in `font-family` definitions is ignored, so "Arial Black" and "ArialBlack" are equivalent.  Bear this in mind and adjust the regular expression if the font name you want to replace has spaces in it.