# How to get width and height of string on the screen?

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, height, width

Lets say I've a string and some font (name, size, etc...).
How to get width and height, measured in pixels, of such string displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy answer is Graphics.MeasureString. But it's rather infamous for not being particularly accurate. If you need better accuracy you can check out this article: [Using MeasureCharacterRanges to Draw Text](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/drawing_text_strings.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify if you were using WinForms or ASP.NET.

If this is a web site, the answer I gave on this question can be easily distilled to a working solution for your question:

[third font in font family is significantly larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118720/third-font-in-font-family-is-significantly-larger/2119438#2119438)

Comment: I'm using WinForms, but Your answer might be helpful in the future, so thanks anyway.