# CSS specify font-size for each font in font-family?

Tags: css

The layout for my main navigation will shift incorrectly if the font used is too large (actually if too wide).

The first font in the font family looks great at a specific font, however the second font (which will be used if they do not have the first) is too wide and will shift the layout.

I did find [this similar quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118720/third-font-in-font-family-is-significantly-larger) which was because the font was too tall. The answer was to use the `ex` unit because it is based off height.

Is there a unit I can use for width, or is there a way to specify the font-size for each font in the font-family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider supplying similar fonts as alternatives. For instance:

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
```

That way, the alternative font won't make the layout break.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally for fonts I would suggest using standard classes such as x-small (extremeley small), small, medium, med-small, large, med-large, x-large etc., and use these classes for different font sizes. Only if you want something really big, you can always use `<h1>, <h2> tags`. I would use % as the standard for all of these. In my usage with various fonts, they rarely have broken the below classes used.

```
.body {
   font-family: arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
}
.x-small {
    font-size: 77%;
   letter-spacing: normal;
}
.small {
    font-size: 85%;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
.med-small {
    font-size: 92%;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
.medium {
    font-size: 100%;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
.med-large {
    font-size: 107%;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
.large {
    font-size: 114%;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
.x-large {
    font-size: 122%;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
.x2-large {
    font-size: 131%;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
.x3-large {
    font-size: 138.5%;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
.strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```