# @font-face and jQuery height() for ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, font-face

I have a situation similar to this question, where I need to equalize element heights while using @font-face:
[jQuery working out wrong height, due to @font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311005/jquery-working-out-wrong-height-due-to-font-face)

Using $(window).load worked at first, but now I need to load in this content dynamically with an AJAX call. Is there anything I can do? Another event I can tap into to determine when the dynamically loaded content has been fully rendered, @font-face and all?

Comment: This could actually be a non-issue. Seems to be working just using the post-ajax event. Unless I get other comments or an answer, will just close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turns out to be a non-issue. It seems that the post-load event for AJAX content behaves like a window.load would, as opposed to a document.ready.

Comment: My guess is that by the time your ajax is processed, the load event already fired. That means you could run into a problem as you load more resources.