# Adjust font size depending on which font is used from a font stack

Tags: html, css, font-size, font-family

I'm using one of the new google api fonts for a heading on a site. It's Yannone Kaffeesatz and is quite a condensed typeface.

My font stack is as follows:

```
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', arial, serif;
```

This is fine when the Yannone Kaffeesatz font renders, but if it doesn't, Arial is much more open and the heading spans over two lines.

My question is:

Is it possible to use a different font-size depending on which font is rendered on the page?

Ideally supported across a multitude of browsers.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: This is a dupe, but I can't find the original

Comment: You can add server based user agent detection, and then serve a different page (or just css). IMO this is the only somewhat elegant solution. Google has a list of browsers and versions which are guaranteed to work. If it's mostly static text you could just use a PNG.

Comment: The original duplicate is probably this one: [Changing Body Font-Size based on Font-Family with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271477/changing-body-font-size-based-on-font-family-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible. It is complex and difficult to find out the actual used font from a `font-family` list even in JavaScript - it's impossible in pure CSS.

If you want to go the JavaScript route, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960817/get-computed-font-family-in-javascript) is a link to a clever method to detect the actual font-family in JavaScript.

Once you know the font used, it's easy to adjust `element.style.letterSpacing` to the required amount.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I had a feeling this was the case. I may have to re-think my stack. I could possibly do something with an overflow or maybe allow it to gracefully run over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

One property which slightly changes font size depending on font is [font-size-adjust](http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/the-little-known-font-size-adjust-css3-property/).  It's CSS3, only supported by Firefox.

But I don't think you want to tweak the size as much as aspect ratio, making Arial narrow.  Squeezing a font (e.g. the letter spacing) becomes ugly quick.  Instead, you should start with more condensed fonts in your stack.

http://pieroxy.net/blog/2014/10/11/the_quest_for_a_condensed_web_font.html studies condensed font options in detail.  One of the trickier findings there is `font-stretch: condensed` which e.g. helps access e.g. Arial Narrow on windows (with Office).