# How do I specify font sizes a list of fonts in the font-family property?

Tags: css, font-size, font-family

As you know, you may pass a space-separated list to font-family. The browser will use the first one that is available after skipping missing fonts.

```
.rule {
    font-family: doesNotExist, myriad-pro, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Now, myriad-pro and Helvetica can both work in my design, provided that myriad-pro is in 12px font and Helvetica in 11px.

How can I tell the browser to use a particular font size for a particular font? I know that I can pass both family and size in the `font` shorthand property, but it will not accept a list of such pairs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjust font size depending on which font is used from a font stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118673/adjust-font-size-depending-on-which-font-is-used-from-a-font-stack)

Comment: Yeah, looks like it isn't possible without a js library (and not totally reliable, at that). Thanks for the link.

Comment: i'm very curious on the question too!

Comment: Yeah - it would be nice if "font" would take a list, but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as stated in the duplicate question (and *that* question's duplicate) there is a js library that can help with font detection, which is something CSS simply cannot do. It uses a simple but clever method for font detection. I will link it here for posterity:

http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/