# Defining alternative fonts

Tags: css, fonts

Can you assign a `font-size` for alternative fonts?

I use `font-family: font1, font2, font3;` but in my current project I am having a hard time finding proper fall back fonts that are at least close to the same size as the original.

Is there someway I can assign a font size per font that is chosen, based on what the user can render?

I am not looking for a lesson in using web safe fonts or trying to start a debate about such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really, really wish there were, and I sincerely hope that someone has some ingenious way to do this and my answer is down-voted because of that ingenious answer, but no... there isn't, at least not with pure CSS.

What you could do, and there are probably libraries to do this, is use JavaScript to detect font-support and then set the font-size based on that detection.

similar question: [Changing Body Font-Size based on Font-Family with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271477/changing-body-font-size-based-on-font-family-with-jquery)

Comment: darn, one can always hope.  i hate having to resort to images to get an effect.   just read your additional info about js, i will have to check that out.

Comment: look you keep adding things...not complaining though.  that link is packed with good info and I am sure if I can't use one directly it will help me conjure up a solution.  glad to know there was a reason i was not getting any answers with my searches since there is not inherent support to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `font-size-adjust` property?
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop

Comment: Won't hurt to implement it for [browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-size-adjust#Browser_Compatibility) that can take advantage of it.

Comment: yeah will be a great solution in the future, only FF support now it looks like