# Set a different font-size for a fallback font

Tags: css, fonts

On my website I use these fonts: `font-family: Segoe UI, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif`

Verdana looks kind of like Segoe UI and is a nice fallback for Macs & iOS devices.
Now the problem is that Verdana is just a lot bigger than Segoe UI so on some devices the fonts are just too big.

I cannot seem to figure out how to set the font-size depending on the font applied; 18px for segoe ui and 16px for verdana for example?

Any idea how I could do this using only css?

thanks!

Comment: *Looks like kinda like... but is hopelessly bigger.* Guess that's not quite the same.

Comment: The font look alike in shape, not in size.

Comment: I think you'll be forced to use JS for this.

Comment: No CSS solution but have a look here, might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271477/changing-body-font-size-based-on-font-family-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ex` unit but its implementation has been buggy for some browsers.
Another alternative is using the [`font-size-adjust`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop) property which is supported by [Gecko powered browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-size-adjust#Browser_Compatibility).

Comment: not really a solution as nothing is well implemented but thanks for the info and hope for the future :p