# CSS Change text if font-face does not exist?

Tags: html, css, web, font-face

Is there a way to change what text is displayed in a HTML file based on if the user has a certain font-face (preferrably without javascript)?

For example if there is a font-face 'AlphaIcons' I want to display:

```
<span>A</span>
```

Else I want to display:

```
<span><img src="apple.png">Apple</span>
```

(Giving the font to users without it is not an option in this case).

Comment: you mean, you want to know if HTML can query a device's data (specifically system fonts) and see if one exists or not? no.  however you can use CSS3 to set a universal font-face that you have placed on the sites server.

Comment: What is the point here? Why would you do that?

Comment: This can't be done natively in CSS. With JavaScript, you could probably hack something together with a hidden, absolutely-positioned `<div>` with the primary font-face set to AlphaIcons and the secondary set to some OTF arbitrarily named through an `@font_face` rule and get its computed height to see if it matches the expected value (preferably with some tolerance for device variance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED***
Check out this post - it may lead you in the right direction:
[Changing Body Font-Size based on Font-Family with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271477/changing-body-font-size-based-on-font-family-with-jquery)

In the first answer, it gives a new library that can detect fonts.  If you can give it a true/false boolean, then you may be able to write in an image swap.

---

I believe CSS can do this already for you, using font-family prioritizes the fonts you want to use.  If it can't find the first font on the user's system, it goes to the next.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

Just use css like so:

```
span {
    font-family:"AlphaIcons", "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

or am I missing something???

If you want to do some fancier fonts using javascript, check out Google's webfont library:
http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: You can replace fonts, but you can't replace text with images

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  He wants to replace a font that isn't there with an IMAGE of the font that isn't there.  Heads up for anyone else answering, if you read it like me.

Comment: Thanks, I used the javascript in the link you provided to detect font, and then change contents of page if the font was missing. My main reason for doing this is because I had some systems with a copyrighted special symbols font that other people wouldn't have and that I can't give out. If the people have it, I want them to see it, and for those who don't I want to a give a text description and maybe alternative image.

Comment: Maybe what you are missing is how to replace a missing font-type face with an image? .. merry xmass

Answer (score 2):

You can't check this with pure HTML or CSS. You **need** Javascript to handle this problem.

Go through the following steps:

- Embed the font files via font-face
- Detect if font-face is avaiable in the clients browser with javascript. e.g. [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) can do the trick
- When font-face isn't available, insert the image into the span with the following code:

**HTML**

```
<span data-image="apple.png">A</span>
```

**Javascipt**

```
// check font face compatibility
if (!Modernizr.fontface) {

    // replace each span content with the right image
    $('span').each(function(){

        // get the image 
        var image = $(this).data('image');

        // insert this image into the span tag  
        $(this).html('<img src="'+image+'" />');
    });
}
```

data-attributes are only one of many possible solutions. Just a little hint.

In general, there a no methods to check the availability of fonts without Javascript.

Comment: To check if font face is available.

Comment: Why do you need modernizer to do that?

Comment: How would you check if this is available?

Comment: Since modernizer uses javascript to do what it does, why don't you use javascript to do the same thing without it?

Comment: Cause this is a simple, easy, fast solution? For sure he can use a little script that checks ONLY if font face is available. Without modernizr. But i think this answer represents the general concept.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19119/discussion-between-slevin-and-rob)